# Java loop output keep on repeating

Tags: java, loops

```
String[] month = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","June","July","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
int[] monthArray = new int[12];
String[][] itemArray = new String[12][10];
```

Variables

```
monthArray[i] = input.nextInt();
itemArray[monthArray[i]-1][e] = input.next();
```

Store a maximum of 5 String values on user input's month.

```
for(int i=0;i<e;e++){
    System.out.println(itemArray[monthArray[i]-1][i]);
}
```

Having a problem displaying the String values (it just keep repeating the first String value) under user input's month.

Comment: Try using `i++` in the for loop.

Comment: i++; not e++; in the for loop

Comment: It would be much easier to follow the question if you included a complete, runnable example.

Answer (score 3):

You are increasing `e` instead of `i` in the last loop. `e` is the limit and not the variable you use for the iteration and thus the loop will not terminate until you overflow `int`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < e; i++ /* Note the usage of i here*/) {
```

Comment: Unless you mention what the exception is I can not help you. Also consider posting a different question for the exception as this problem seem to be unrelated to what you originally asked.

Comment: It's a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error on this line.
It doesn't read -1 value.
`System.out.println(itemArray[monthArray[i]-1][i]);`

Comment: @shinichi the exception is descriptive enough - it means you are accessing an index out of bounds for the Array. As stated above please do not post this as a comment to my answer, neither edit the original question. The correct way to ask a different thing is to post another question. Sorry. That is how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 2):

use i++ instead of e++
here e stands for the limit
and i stands for the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a 2D array, maybe you want something more like this, to print out the values, once, the array has been populated.

```
String[][] itemArray = new String[12][10];

for(int i = 0; i < itemAreray.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < itemArray[i].legnth; j++){
        System.out.println(itemArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Unless you're having difficulty populating the array. Then that's a different problem